# How can I determine the records with the top N values of a column?

Tags: powerquery, m

I have a table with a numeric column called "Count" and I want to determine the records with the top 10 values in that column. I tried using `List.MaxN([Count],10)` but it throws an error:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value 0 to type list.
Details:
  Value = 0
  Type = Type
```

I also tried `Table.MaxN(_,[Count],10)` and got an error.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the top 10 values of the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the table name, like

```
= List.MaxN(MyTable[Count],10)
```

Comment: Thanks @MarcelBeug. And for the Table.MaxN, I figured out I needed to use quotes instead of brackets. ...and least that's what appeared to work.